# How do I get the next open number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL column that looks like this.

[image]

Notice how there are numbers in the 1100s and the 2000s (1101 - 1123 do not show but they exist). I wrote a script to make it so that users who sign up with a certain group will get a login corresponding to that group. So, if they sign up in the basic group, they are given the first available login in the 1100s. If they sign up in the moderate group, then they get the first available login in the 2000s. Say that user AAL2002 is deleted, the next person to join should take the login 2002, not 2007 (so that the gaps are automatically filled).

Right now I have a PHP script that tries to look through everything and give them a new, unused login. The problem is that it duplicates some logins. Is there any other way to do this with PHP and SQL?

Here's my horrible, confusing code if you think it can be fixed:

```
$husers = Query::runQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `group`=? AND `login` NOT BETWEEN 'AAL1000' AND 'AAL1010'", array($post['group']));
            $i = 0;
            $f = false;
            do
            {
                $baseid = (substr($users[$i]['login'], 3)) + 1;

                if($baseid != substr($users[$i+1]['login'], 3))
                {
                    $checkid = Query::runQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`=?", array("AAL".$baseid));

                    if($checkid[0]['login'] != "AAL".$baseid)
                    {
                        $f = true;
                    }

                }

                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: It would be easier if you had the number in an INTEGER column.

Comment: @Barmar That is part of the problem.

Comment: Neither of the two answers given help me.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work at all if you have more than one user registering at the same time (race condition). You can work around that by using database transactions.
On top of that, you should do the finding and registering the next free ID for your user with a SQL function. Together with transactions, this will give you a solution that also works even if you script is called by more than one person at a time.

In the mysql would, one usually just uses and auto-increment column to avoid this kind of problem. On most other databases and if you do not use an continuous integer column, you have to go the hard way.

Comment: transactions don't help. just make the column unique.

Comment: He would still override users if two scripts run concurrently and happen to acquire the same ID. This is why locking is needed and the most simple way is to use transactions.

Comment: 1) you cannot overwrite with `insert`. 2) transactions don't solve the problem. if you want *locking*, you need locks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

```
CREATE TABLE login (
    login VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO login (login) 
    VALUES ('1100'), ('1101'), ('1102'), ('1106'), ('1107');
```

Querying:

```
SELECT MIN(login) + 1 AS result FROM (
    SELECT login,
        (SELECT MIN(l2.login) FROM login l2 WHERE l2.login = l.login + 1) AS next
    FROM login l
    HAVING next IS NULL
) AS list;
```

Gives the following result:

```
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|   1103 |
+--------+
```

My example uses only the integer part of your alpha + decimal field. This spares me to do [substring operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), grouping based on prefix ("`AAL11`", "`AAL20`") and eventual casts (perhaps not necessary as I demonstrate with varchar) but nevertheless shows how it *could* be done. I leave that as an exercise.

As already discussed, you can run the lookup + insert operation only together. That means you need to have this as an atomic operation in your application (commonly known as transaction, but I do not mean SQL transaction by that).

Comment: I'm not very versed in SQL, but I guess it should look like this?

SELECT MIN(SUBSTRING(login , 3, 4)) + 1 AS result FROM (
     SELECT SUBSTRING(login , 3, 4),
      (SELECT MIN(SUBSTRING(l2.login , 3, 4)) FROM SUBSTRING(login , 3, 4) l2 WHERE SUBSTRING(l2.login , 3, 4) = SUBSTRING(l.login , 3, 4) + 1) AS next
     FROM SUBSTRING(login , 3, 4) l
     HAVING next IS NULL
    ) AS list

Comment: Also, I have no idea how to do grouping based on prefix.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: I didn't mean SQL transcation, I meant transaction on the application level. Perhaps should have written atomic operation.